# How can validation control on submitting event React-Final-Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

I have a wizard form, I want to submit a validation check and if there is a missing value in the form, I want to direct the user to that page number and show it. Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

**I solved.**
*I added :*

```
    if (!values.personal_name) { 
let personalNameValidation = new Promise(function (resolve) 
{ setTimeout(function () { resolve({ personal_name: required() }); }, 100); // should be same field name });
 this.setState(() => ({ page: 0 })) 
return personalNameValidation
}
```

*to form **submit function** and added*

```
{(meta.error || meta.submitError) && meta.touched && ( <span className="form-control-error-label">{meta.error || meta.submitError}</span> )}
```

to my **renderField.**